SharePoint Designer Workflow Advice
In SharePoint, we have a form that employees can submit to HR that is basically an employee recommendation. HR reviews the form, then sends to the employee's supervisor to approve or reject.  I'd like to set a workflow that is triggered to automatically send to the employee's supervisor once HR sets an "initial review" option to approved.  The email that gets sent will include a link to that specific form.  My problem is that I have the workflow set to go when an item has been changed, but I've gotten feedback that people are receiving multiple emails.
How do I set the workflow to just send one email, but no more than that?  I think every time HR modifies an item in the list, a new email is being sent to the approving manager.
